# translated viewe name on BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

is there any way to see the translated view name on BIM360 using Forge API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 3 ways to do this:

1. the [manifest endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) contains that information. See the name property in the example below.

```
{
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2...bGFnZUJJTS5ydnQ",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "children": [
                {
                    "guid": "53a6e995-4cf9-0aa6-c3ef-68a4b6150dbf",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "name": "{3D}",
                    "viewableID": "8a8b24b1-b87d-4238-adcc-ef2c1ea155aa-0005d884",
                    "phaseNames": "Nouvelle construction",
                    "status": "success",
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "guid": "f16dbf36-6b14-4da3-abcd-5ff97b894304-0005da20",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "role": "2d",
                    "name": "A101 - Sans nom",
                    "viewableID": "f16dbf36-6b14-4da3-abcd-5ff97b894304-0005da20",
                    "status": "success",
                    ...
                },
                ...
             ],
             ...
        },
        ...
}
```

2. If you are running in the viewer, you can either use

- the [Document Browser Extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/DocumentBrowser/) which would give you the same look and feel that you got in BIM360 to navigate in the 3d and 2d viewws.
- Or you can use the [Viewer Document search API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/BubbleNode/#search-propstomatch) and find all views, like this

```
doc.getRoot().search({
    type: 'geometry',
    //role: '3d' // optional filter, could be 2d or 3d, comment to get all
})
```

Comment: thank you so much, Cyrille. Great answer :)